# Table size grows indefinitely after deleting and then inserting the same data

Tags: oracle, insert, table, delete, size

I create a table and populate it with data:

```sql
create table tab
as
select 'value' || level val
from dual
connect by level <= 10000;
```

If I then delete all rows and insert the same data:

```sql
delete from tab;

insert into tab
select 'value' || level val
from dual
connect by level <= 10000;

commit;
```

The table size increases every time delete-then-insert is performed. Executing these operation multiple times causes the table to grow to many times it's original size.

I would expect the size to remain (approximately) the same. Why is this happening?

A delete marks space as free, it doesn't actually shrink the segment. A subsequent insert should first use available empty blocks below HWM.

I can recover the space using `alter table tab shrink space`.

I tested in Oracle 12 and Oracle 18c.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have access to My Oracle Support:

[Space Used By Tables Are Not Being Re-used With Repeat Delete/insert Operation (Doc ID 1601805.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1601805.1)

So, without just copy-pasting the contents from there, the above note states:

- the space management algorithm prefers allocating more space over reusing already allocated but free space
- this is not a bug, but a feature, this is how it was designed
- you can use shrink to compact the segment, as you have already discovered

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to My Oracle Support. Is there a way I can control this behavior? The limitation of manual table shrink is that it cannot be used on compressed tables.

Comment: I ended up with disabling compression and schedling shrinking space periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Delete, use TRUNCATE TABLE command.

Comment: I considered that. Unfortunately, I need the delete and insert to execute in one transaction.

Comment: Why are you creating the table each time? It seems that you are creating a table, then deleting it and reinserting the same data. Is that correct?

Comment: I encountered this issue in a materialized view that was regularly refreshed (`COMPLETE` mode). After investigating I noticed that I can get the same effect with delete-then-insert on a regular table (materialized view must be doing that under the hood).